# Why $|\sqrt{a}-i|=\sqrt{a+1}$ for every nonnegative real number $a$?

Tags: complex-numbers

> Why $|\sqrt{a}-i|=\sqrt{a+1}$ for every nonnegative real number $a$?

I know that $i=\sqrt{-1}$, and in my textbook I get $$|\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}-i|=\sqrt{(x^2+(y-1)^2)^2+(-1)^2}=\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2+1}$$

I can't find how the first two passages are connected.

Edit: corrected equation.

Comment: I don't get it.  Let $x=2$ and $y=1$ to see that this is false.

Comment: They are not... Take $a=1$. I highly doubt $1-i=\sqrt 2$...

Comment: For every nonnegative real number $a$, $$|\sqrt a-i|^2=(\sqrt a-i)\overline{(\sqrt a+i)}=(\sqrt a-i)(\sqrt a+i)$$ hence $$|\sqrt a-i|^2=a-i^2=a+1$$ which is equivalent to the desired identity $$|\sqrt a-i|=\sqrt{a+1}$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I corrected the equation.

Comment: Thank you @Did!

Comment: ...With a typo in my comment, which I hope you were able to correct.

Comment: @KaiWen if you edited exactly what is written in your textbook, then you are right. There is a typo in the textbook, $\sqrt$ is forgotten. Should be $|\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2}-i|=\sqrt{(\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2})^2+(-1)^2}=\sqrt{x^2+(y-1)^2+1}$